# Minecraft Timer reset by Death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking to make a server that resets a command_block timer every time you die. eventually I'm going to hook this up to a store system that rewards people with better Armour sets and such. any suggestions would be awesome.

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0):

Manually create a [deathCount objective](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria):

```
/scoreboard objectives add death deathCount
```

Then when that [score becomes one](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_score)(player death), reset their timer score and their death score:

```
execute @a[score_death_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players reset @s timer
execute @a[score_death_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players reset @s death
```